# Wix: Replace System.Message with custom self developed messagebox

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn

I am using wix for creating our installer. Our UI team has developed our own messagebox and is present in dll. I want to replace system messagebox with my messagebox. 
When I try to use our messagebox and put a try catch then it says:
 InnerException System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'XXX' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have added the dll in the references of bootstrapper. How can I use it? I think as it embedded in the exe this might not be found. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your messagebox dll into the Payload for the BootstrapperApplication. You should be able to use something like this to get it included:

```
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixExtBATheme">
    <Payload Name='CustomMessageBox.dll' Compressed='yes' SourceFile='$(var.OutDir)$(var.Configuration)\CustomMessageBox.dll'/>
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>
```

What this does is tell the bootstrapper to include this file as part of the required files when the program runs. When you run the Bootstrapper Exe, it extracts all the payload files into a temp directory and then runs the actual setup.exe from that dir. If you put your DLL as a payload file, it should be present in the same directory as the setup.exe and thus will find the DLL eventually.

Comment: +1 Thanks! with this my exception is gone and it is able to show the messagebox. But the styling is not visible. This style is present in the dll itself. For other views it is added as Resource dictonary and it works fine. How can add this style in the BA?
Currently for views it is added this way: 
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyApp.WPFStyles;component/MyStyles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>...

Comment: When it comes to WPF and xaml I don't know what is happening, sorry.